# Error: invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier for foreign key constraint

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

Does anyone know why my two tables in SQL developer produce the error of:

```
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00904: "CLIENT_ID": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier".
```

I know it is to do with the constraints for the foreign keys but don't know why:

```
CREATE TABLE person

( person_id NUMBER(4) not null,

person_name VARCHAR(50),

person_surname VARCHAR(50),

person_contact_number NUMBER(11),

person_address VARCHAR2(50),

person_postcode VARCHAR2(50),

fk_boss_id NUMBER(4),

CONSTRAINT person_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (person_id),

CONSTRAINT boss_id FOREIGN KEY (boss_id) REFERENCES boss (boss_id)
);



CREATE TABLE boss

( boss_id NUMBER(4) not null,

boss_name VARCHAR(50),

fk_person_id NUMBER(4),

CONSTRAINT boss_pk PRIMARY KEY (boss_id),

CONSTRAINT person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (person_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key constraints say that the columns `person.boss_id` and `boss.person_id` are foreign keys, but neither table has a column by that name. It looks as though you've swapped the names of the FK *columns* with those of the FK *constraints*.

The `FOREIGN KEY` clause of the `CONSTRAINT` declaration must reference a column ***that exists*** in the declaring table. For instance, in the table `boss` you would have

```
...
person_id NUMBER(4),
...
CONSTRAINT fk_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (person_id)
...
```

(Also, if your error message begins `ORA` then you're using Oracle, not MySQL, and if it refers to a column called `CLIENT_ID` then it's complaining about a third table which is neither of the ones you posted.)